# .htaccess: block fake referers from my own domain

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've got a tricky problem using .htaccess.  I've got a whole load of bots eating up bandwidth on my site that are presenting fake referers that appear to come from my site.  I've Googled and also looked on here but can't see any way to stop this (which may be why they are doing it !)

As an example, one bot sends the referer domain.com/accessories/fake_file1 whilst another sends the fake referer domain.com/bikes/fake_file2.

I know that .htaccess can be used to block by referer but all the documentation that I've found suggests that you can only block on a per domain basis and I'm really reluctant to put my own domain name in as the domain to block as I'm sure that'll screw something up !

Is there a way to do something like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
# Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} mydomain\.com\/fake_dir1/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} mydomain\.com\/fake_dir2/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} mydomain\.com\/fake_dir3/ [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pur `[OR]` clause as:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} mydomain\.com/fake_dir1/ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} mydomain\.com/fake_dir2/ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} mydomain\.com/fake_dir3/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

OR with a better regex:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} mydomain\.com/(fake_dir1|fake_dir2|fake_dir3)/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

#### UPDATE:

1. To test this rule I created this PHP code:

   ```
   <?php
   $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "localhost/go/1z67");
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'mydomain.com/accessories/water-bottles-and-cages/…');
   $html = curl_exec($ch);
   curl_close($ch);  
   var_dump($html);
   ?>
   ```
2. And this rule in my `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

   ```
   RewriteEngine on

   RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} mydomain\.com/accessories/ [NC]
   RewriteRule ^ - [F]
   ```

And then when I ran that curl script I got this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Forbidden</h1>
<p>You don't have permission to access /go/1z67
on this server.</p>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply - it occured to me that the url's are actually like this: mydomain\.com/fake_dir1/file_1 & mydomain\.com/fake_dir1/file_2.  The regex won't work for those - if I add .* it should though ? e.g. mydomain\.com/fake_dir1/.* ?

Comment: Sure that's not the problem you can always use the first form of rule with different URL in each line with `[OR]` condition.

Comment: And yes you can use **`RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} mydomain\.com/fake_dir1/`** to catch all these cases

Comment: Hmm, it's not working.  I've added this to my .htaccess [code]RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} domain\.com/accessories/.* [NC,OR] but if I access a url on my site using a php script containing curl with the referer set to 'domain.com/accessories/shimano-fishing-rod it's not blocked - the page still appears

Comment: Can you provide your curl command then I can also test it from my end and edit the answer accordingly.

Comment: [code]curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.domain.com/go/1z67");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://www.domain.com/accessories/water-bottles-and-cages/elite-nature-corsa-water-bottle-550ml/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Referer Test');[/code]

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42604/discussion-between-user1647208-and-anubhava)